# Создание бота на Python + JS

Tags: javascript, python

Мне нужно создать одну программу. В ней требуются знания JS, которых у меня пока нет.
Программа должна выполнять следующие действия :

В файле Python :

```
if условие :
    Открыть файл JS и выполнить его.
```

В файле JS :

```
Проверить, поступили ли деньги на Qiwi.
Когда деньги появляются, программа переходит на один сайт.
Там заполняет формы и отправляет их.
Заходит на mail.ru и ищет письмо, которое пришло после отправки формы.
В письме ищет определенные строки и отправляет пользователю VK
```

Comment: тут не js нужен, а браузерный движок

Comment: Большинство реализуется на JS. Например, заполнение форм, проверка строк. Где-то примеры видел, но под свою программу их интерпретировать сложновато, когда знаний в JS никаких

Comment: Тут не нужен js, это всё можно сделать на питоне

Comment: Поясните, как можно реализовать на питоне.

Comment: Вместо заполнения формы составляете http запрос нужным методом с нужными данными и заголовками, парсите ответ, вынимаете нужную информацию. Повторить в нужном порядке со всеми нужными сервисами

Comment: Можно ли пример кодом? Просто я пока не шарю, как пайтон может работать с браузером.

Comment: Вам вообще не нужен браузер

Comment: Я к сожалению не знаю питон, но такое можно проделать на любом языке, где можно послать http запрос

Comment: Гуглить "html парсер на питоне"

Comment: https://habrahabr.ru/post/280238/

Comment: Хорошо. Как можно закрыть вопрос или репутации вам дать? Я минут 10 назад зарегестрировался

Comment: Репутации у меня достаточно, спасибо) Насчет закрыть - вы можете удалить свой вопрос, либо подождать, пока пользователи с нужными привилегиями проголосуют за закрытие вопроса, потому что, по хорошему, он слишком общий.